# Tubeplayer causing elements to (briefly) reappear in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube-javascript-api

I'm working on some javascript to insert a youtube video into a page using the [tubeplayer](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin) plugin. The video is inserted when the user clicks a link and is removed when the user clicks the close button.

For the most part, the script works fine. When the user clicks the close button, the button slides away, the video player fades out, the container fades out, and everything looks the way it did before the user clicked the link.

In Chrome, however, after everything has faded out, the video and the close button will occasionally re-appear in a brief flash. It's not consistent - it only occurs about half the time - but it looks bad.

I've tried all sorts of things to fix this - hiding elements, not hiding elements, removing elements at various point in the script - and it keeps happening. The only thing I'm certain of is that tubeplayer is a necessary element; if I take tubeplayer out and just show / hide the other elements, the flash does not occur.

I'm at a total loss about how to prevent this from happening. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Here's my markup:

```
<section id="hero">
  <div class="item-content">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sC_IESaVT0A" class="youtube">
      <img src="/dynamic-content/solutions/hero_content_mobility.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jnet.ytplayer.init('#hero', 711, 400, '#000');
    });
</script>
```

And the script:

```
ytplayer = {

    $target:null,
    height:null,
    width:null,
    background:null,
    defaults:{
     allowFullScreen: "true",
     initialVideo: 'FtUtE_kv7DU',
     preferredQuality: "default",
     showControls: 1,
     showRelated: 0,
     autoPlay: 1,
     autoHide: 3,
     border: 0,
     theme: 'dark',
     wmode: 'opaque',
     origin: document.domain,
     swfobjectURL: "/assets/js/jquery/plugins_jq.js",
     allowScriptAccess: "always",
     playerID: "tubeplayer-player-container",
     loadSWFObject: false,
     iframed: true,
     onPlayerEnded: function(){
         ytplayer.removeVideo();
        }
    },
    init:function(target, w, h, bg){
        this.$target = $(target);
        this.defaults.height = h;
        this.defaults.width = w;
        this.background = bg;

    },
    showVideo:function(link){
        var id = $(link).attr("href").replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "");
        this.defaults.initialVideo = id;
        var markup = "<div id='youtube-container'>";
        markup +=           "<div id='youtube-player'>";
        markup +=            "<div id='youtube-closeBtn'></div>";
        markup +=            "<div id='youtube'></div>";
        markup +=           "</div>";
        markup +=       "</div>";
        this.$target.prepend(markup);
        $('#youtube-closeBtn').click(function(){
            ytplayer.removeVideo();
        });

        $('#youtube-container').height(this.defaults.height);
        $('#youtube-container').css('background', this.background);
        $('#youtube').height(this.defaults.height);
        $('#youtube').width(this.defaults.width);
        $('#youtube-player').height(this.defaults.height);
        $('#youtube-player').width(this.defaults.width);
        $('#youtube-container').fadeIn(200);
            $('#youtube-player').fadeIn(600, function() {
                $('#youtube').tubeplayer(ytplayer.defaults);
                $('#youtube-closeBtn').show();
                $('#youtube-closeBtn').animate({ 'right' : '-=49' }, 600, function(){
            });
        });
    },
    removeVideo:function(){
        $('#youtube-closeBtn').animate({'right' : '+=49'}, 200, function() {
            $('#youtube-closeBtn').hide();
            $('#youtube').tubeplayer('stop');
            $('#youtube-player').fadeOut(600, function(){
                $('#youtube-container').fadeOut(100, function(){
                    $('#youtube-container').remove();
                });
            });
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle or anything I can play with? would love to help resolve this (author of said plugin).

Comment: Wow! I haven't even looked at this code in ages, but I just revisited it and there doesn't seem to be a problem. Thanks for asking, and keep up the good work!